# Python number processing trouble

Tags: python

I want to write a program that asks a user how many numbers they wish to process, then ask for that many numbers. Then it will find the total and the maximum of the numbers processed. Example output:

```
Enter the number of values to process: 5

First value: 3
Next value: 9.2
Next value: -2.5
Next value: 0.25
Next value: 6

The total is 15.95
The maximum is 9.20
```

One thing I am lost on is that if if I have the code `for num in (1, 3)`
and `num` gets assigned multiple values, how do I extract both those values?

Comment: To store multiple values in one variable, use a list.

Comment: Set `example_list = list()`, then do a `for` loop where each time you ask for input and add the value to the list via `example_list.append(input_response)`. Extract the values back out by doing another `for` loop to cycle through the list: `for stored_number in example_list: do stuff`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  for information on writing a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `example_list = list()`, then do a `for` loop where each time you ask for input and add the value to the list via `example_list.append(input_response)`.

Extract the values back out using the same `for` loop to cycle through the list.

```
example_list = list()
total = 0
max_value = 0

for stored_number in example_list:
    # Ask for input and store in input_response variable
    example_list.append(input_response)

    # Here is where you could add the values to a counter variable, 
    # as well as check whether they are the maximum
    total += stored_number
    if stored_number > max:
        max_value = stored_number

# Display results
```

For what you want, you could also just use the built-in functions max and sum:

```
max_value = max(example_list)
total = sum(example_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# ask how many
quantity = int(raw_input("Enter the number of values to process: "))
# ask for numbers and store them in list
numbers = [float(raw_input("Enter number " + str(each) + " : ")) for each in range(0,quantity)]
#print result
print "The total is " + str(sum(numbers)) + " and the maximum is " + str(max(numbers))
```

Comment: @Evan Nichos: might want to check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?#list-comprehensions) and [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?#more-on-lists) out